# How to order recordset by number of occurrences of a field value and sort by it

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting, group-by

I'm running a query
`select * from transactions` which gives me the recordsets

```
ppno ---------name---------------amnt
1309 ---------Rajasekar----------12000
1210 ---------Mani     ----------21000
1309 ---------Sank     ----------90012
1100 ---------still    ----------12232
1309 ---------Jack     ----------23344
```

I want to group the resultset by number of occurrences of the same `ppno` and sort it based on the number of occurrences. For example, I want something like this.

```
ppno ---------name---------------amnt
1309 ---------Rajasekar----------12000
1309 ---------Sank     ----------90012
1309 ---------Jack     ----------23344
1210 ---------Mani     ----------21000    
1100 ---------still    ----------12232
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.*
from transactions t
order by (
    select count(1) from transactions t2 where t2.ppno = t.ppno
) desc, t.ppno desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.ppno, t.name, t.amnt
    FROM (SELECT ppno, COUNT(*) AS ppnoCount
              FROM transactions
              GROUP BY ppno) c
        INNER JOIN transactions t
            ON c.ppno = t.ppno
    ORDER BY c.ppnoCount DESC, t.ppno
```